# Ruby Rails Database Relationships - One to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-relationship

This is mainly a theoritical question, but just wanted to make sure that i'm doing it correctly. Consider a Ruby Rails project where there are two models, one being User and the other being Alliance.

A user can only have one alliance.
An alliance can have many users.

That is very much simply a :has_many, :belongs_to relationship.

However, i feel that using an intermediate model is a better way to do it. That would be a :has_many :through :users_alliances, where users_alliances would be an intermediate model.

What do you think is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use habtm, it doesn't make the join into a fully fledged model, which is what you need.  Use has_many :through on the alliance side and has_one :through on the user side.

```
User
  has_one :alliance_membership
  has_one :alliance, :through => :alliance_membership

AllianceMembership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :alliance

Alliance 
  has_many :alliance_memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :alliance_memberships
```

Personally i prefer the class name AllianceMembership to UserAlliance but you could use either.  UsersAlliances is ugly though imo.  (another advantage of has_many/one :through is that you can call the join table/class whatever you want).

This gives you the option to easily change to users having many alliances later on if you want.

Comment: Just great, thank you ! Just a small subquestion. Using habtm, i see that the third table is automatically populated. I suppose i'm doing something wrong, but when i create an alliance now, shouldn't the alliance_memberships table be automatically populated ? (alliance is scaffold generated). And btw, alliance_memberships is indeed much better, i'm using this now :)

Comment: hmm, well, on some thought, i suppose i will have to use the new AllianceMembership as the object to pass the new membership to the alliance, duh :P I'll try that to make sure.

Comment: ahhh, got it. "@alliance.users << current_user", just great :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that? What do you think you'll gain from the join model?

Personally I doubt the extra table/model would be helpful, unless you think that one-to-many will become many-to-many in the future.

Comment: The idea is that some information that refers to a user in the alliance should be stored there. For instance, the rank of the user in the alliance, i think it's better to be part of the join table. It's more explicit i think.

Comment: You have a point. Thats also how its done in World of Warcraft for guilds. Look for table guild and guild members here: https://github.com/mangos/mangos/blob/master/sql/characters.sql

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as i was thinking it. However, it seems that there is no documentation for this type of relationship and i cannot really get the intermediate table (users_alliances) automatically populated as would happen with a habtm relationship. :/